# Do tree methods like gradient boosting predict all iterations at once?

Tags: forecasting, random-forest, boosting, bagging

If I'm using a tree method (e.g GBM) and I have a time series hourly data, and I predict my target variable $y$ for the next 48 hours, do my predictions were made all at once, or does the second day of prediction already use my first day of prediction as input?

For example, when I'm predicting $y$ at hour 2, does the model have in account the predicted value of $y$ at hour 1; and when I'm predicting $y$ at hour 3, does it have in account the value of $y$ at hour 2? and so on..
Or does the model predict all of the 48 values of $y$ without any connection between them (independently)?

I have all of the feature variables for the 48 hours, I only need to predict my target variable $y$. Basically, what I'm asking is if the method uses predictions to predict further ahead or does it predict all at once?

(The data does not have any lag features)

Comment: Am I correct that you have $p$ features at each of $T$ time steps in an $T \times p$ matrix $X$? And you're using row $t$ in $X$ to predict $y_t$, a scalar? In other words, the only difference between the typical non-time-series GBT model and your model is that instead of exchangeable, atomic observations, your observations are indexed by time?

Comment: I use variables like day, hour, month, year, etc, as input variables

Comment: $y$ is a continuous variable

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to understand if there's anything about your model that makes it different from a model that's not a time series, or if the temporal nature of your task is purely incidental to what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think so. The data is a time series but I use my data as tabular data where the datetime column is the index and I have columns like day, year, hour, month, etc

Comment: Ok, so if the data are essentially tabular, and each row of the feature matrix is used to predict the target for that particular row, it seems that you have your answer -- if you need the prediction 48-hours in the future, them you'll need to provide the features for 48-hours in the future.

Comment: Yes I know. My question is not about the features. My question is about the target variable $y$

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to explain what you know and what you'd like to know in more detail. If you agree that you need to give feature for the hour you want to predict, I don't understand how there's anything left to be answered. Here's an illustration: get predictions for just $x(t)$, the features at time $t$. Then get the predictions for $x(t-1), x(t), x(t+1)$. The predictions for $x(t)$ will be the same in either case. Is this what you're asking about? Or are you asking about something else (and what is it?)?

Comment: @Sycorax Sorry if I made myself not very clear and sorry for my bad english. I edited my question, do you understand it now?

Comment: Is $y(t-k)$ a feature for $x(t)$? In other words, does your feature matrix includes lags of $y$?

Comment: It does not have any lag features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you outline in the post and in comments, the predictions are atomic. Predictions for the feature vector of time $t$ don't depend on the feature vectors for any other times. This is because the time-series nature of the data is not reflected in any part of this model; the data are essentially a tabular.

All we need to do to verify this claim is show that predictions for tabular data don't change when you supply 1 or several vectors for prediction.

It's easy enough to verify this by writing a test:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_hastie_10_2
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
import numpy as np

X, y = make_hastie_10_2(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test = X[:2000], X[2000:]
y_train, y_test = y[:2000], y[2000:]

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=1.0, max_depth=1, random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
foo = clf.predict_proba(X_test[10,:].reshape(1,-1))
bar = clf.predict_proba(X_test[0:11,:])
np.testing.assert_allclose(foo, bar[10,:].reshape(1,-1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've run your code and got no warning message, so I can assume that the predictions are made independently, right?

Comment: I'm just waiting for your confirmation to accept your answer.

Comment: Yes. The numpy testing function will raise an exception if the values aren’t sufficiently close. No exception implies that the values are sufficiently close.